# Android Studio. Taking picture of phone

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

Hey guys just wondering how to take a picture of my phone while it is connected to the computer in android studio. If you know a program that will allow me to take a pic of my phone's screen, app or on the computer, then please let me know.

Thanks for the help 
:)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#screenCap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio can do it!
Look for the tab called `Android Monitor` at the bottom, then look for the little camera icon.

That's it!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Distwo, sorry I'm kind of new to stack overflow.